# BB10 how to generate config.pri file

Tags: eclipse, blackberry-10, qnx

Is there a script or a tool to generate the config.pri file for a BB10 project? Momentics IDE does it for you automatically whenever a project is refreshed or the directory is changed. Unfortunately, I am deploying and compiling via command line tools (it is an automated script which runs tests).

Without the config.pri file, I can't 'make'. An easy solution would be to track the file on github along with the source code for the project, but since the file has a timestamp on it, it causes many annoying merge conflicts.

Any ideas? I rather not write the script myself to parse through all the directories and accumulate header and source files myself. Since Momentics IDE does it, there must be a script that it calls or uses. Momentics is based off of Eclipse, is there any way to see what commands the IDE is calling?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

`config.pri` is just an additional file included in the project's main `.pro` file. So if you're able to control `.pro` file you may not need `config.pri` at all and this inclusion could be safely removed from `.pro` file. For example, in earlier BB10 SDK releases `config.pri` simply didn't exist and has been added later.

`.pro` file is a main file for generating platform and environment-dependent `Makefiles` for building project, so I'm not sure if there's some tools allowing to manage it automatically. It could be *initially* generated by invoking `qmake -project` but I'm not sure if there are any console tools allowing you to manage it after automatically.

Technically, you should modify this file only if your project structure or build system options changed, all other stuff is done in platform-independent way.